# Handing over facebook developed app to customer

Tags: facebook

Can someone please help me identify the process of handing over developed facebook app to customer ? how to I transfer the control over to the customers users and remove my facebook id from the app ?

-Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about the legalities of transfer-of-control, but the technicality is as follows:

Go to your app settings' roles section (https://developers.facebook.com/apps/XXX/permissions) and change the roles. You will first have to add your customers as the "Administrators" and your customers will have to accept it by going to developers.facebook.com/apps. Once they have accepted their Administrator status, request them to remove you from the roles (I believe you may be able to remove yourself - but I am not too sure about it.)

Please remember that your customers will have to be "Approved" user (by inputting and verifying their phone number or credit card) before they can accept the "Administrator" status.

Comment: They don't need to be friends as far as I know, you can add by user ID

Comment: Igy: Thanks. Just recalled the same. Corrected my answer.